# Regarding the Definition of Holomorphic Foliation on a Complex Manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, fibration, complex-manifolds, foliations

**Geometry, Dynamics And Topology Of Foliations: A First Course**, Book by **Bruno Scárdua** and **Carlos Arnoldo Morales Rojas**, Chapter **1**, Page **33**. Definition **1.14**.

The definition of **Holomorphic Foliation** on a **Complex Manifold**.

What do they mean by (Given any intersection $U_i\cap U_j\neq\phi$ the change of coordinates $\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i ^{-1}$ preserves the horizontal fibration on $\mathbb{C}^n \simeq\mathbb{C}^k \times \mathbb{C}^{n-k}$)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that for all $w \in \mathbb C^{n-k}$ there exists $z \in \mathbb C^{n-k}$ such that
$$\phi_j \circ \phi_i^{-1}\bigl(\phi_i(U_i \cap U_j) \cap (\mathbb C^k \times \{w\})\bigr) \subset \phi_j(U_i \cap U_j) \cap (\mathbb C^k \times\{z\})
$$
This has nothing to do with holomorphicity or complex manifolds per se. You'll find similar definitions of foliations on real manifolds, with any level of smoothness.